# google closure compiler, PRETTY_PRINT and object literal

Tags: javascript, json, google-closure-compiler, object-literal

I have a file.js file with a variable whose value is an (nested) object literal. Something like

```
var ojb = {
    foo: {
        bar: 'baz'
    },
    quux: [
        { /* stuff */ },
        { /* stuff */ }
    ]
};
```

I use google closure compiler in conjunction with the options `--formatting=PRETTY_PRINT` and `--compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY` because I just want it to "clean" the output (remove the comments, uniform the braces...) but I found it "inlines" the object literal: the output contains

```
 var obj = {"foo":{"bar":"baz"},"quux":[{...},{...}]};
```

which is "illegible".

Is there a way to tell the compiler to span object literals on various lines (ideally I want a syntax like the output of http://jsonlint.com )

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a JavaScript **beautifier** instead?  Pass the Closure output to an on-line beautifier.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since my comment *is* the actual answer to your question, I'll just post it here:
 the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` compilation might well be the least invasive of all *compilation modes* but as the docs clearly state:

> The WHITESPACE_ONLY compilation level removes comments from your code and also removes line breaks, unnecessary spaces, and other whitespace. The output JavaScript is functionally identical to the source JavaScript.

From [the docs, on compilation modes](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels). As you can read on this page, the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` compilation returns the most human-readable code of all modes. All other modes execute the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` compilation, and do other stuff in addition to that.
To answer your question: No, there is no way to tell the compiler to leave excessive white-space unchanged for some code, and go crazy on other parts of your code. The only thing you *can* do is write a script, that extracts the object literals you want preserved and save them to a separate file. After compiling the original, you can replace the in-lined versions of those object literals with their "white-space-heavy" counterparts.

But since you're so keen on keeping your code readable, I'd strongly suggest either *not* minifying anything, or use the *pretty-print* button in your console, twined with the other neat features the console provides you with to inspect objects. 
An even better approach would be: to write your code, and test it extensively and only minify/compile *for production* (IE: when you're done with the coding/debugging). After all, that's how these tools were meant to be used.

Comment: You are right for all, but I use the "WHITESPACE_ONLY" exactly for production: sometimes we need to do a double-check for bugs in production, or update some configurations (the variable is a "configuration object"). When some (minor) changes have to be deployed, I need to pass a patch file with the modification. Unfortunately when the configuration object is so inlined, the diff isn't obvious as with a diff on the "not-inlined" version... If there isn't an option with google closure compiler, I need a tool to just "strip comments out" of this file...

Comment: @VitoDeTullio: I guess you're back to writing your own script, then. Though you could use [jsstrip](http://code.google.com/p/jsstrip/) for inspiration

Comment: If you wanted submit a patch that handled object literals better when pretty printing, I would support it.

Comment: @John: Join the club :), I've got my own script to do just that (written in Perl), but it's all but perfect... Maybe I'll set up a github for it this weekend. _That's not a promise, just a maybe_ :-P